# Redirect user to previous page

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, joomla

I want to redirect users to the page they came from , but not using javascript go.back and stuff like that , because it doesn't load the page again .

I found some code

```
<?php 
$ref1 = urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); 
$ref2 = urlencode('http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=page2.php?ref1='.$ref1.'&amp;ref2='.$ref2.'">'; 
?>
```

I just want a PHP file to take the previous URL , the exact URL , and then send the user back to it . I am using PHP because it causes the page to load again .
I used javascript , but it doesn't load the page again , so please help me here .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: what was wrong about `javascript:window.location.reload(history.go(-1));`?

Comment: HTTP_REFERER may not work in all case but exactly when you are trying to do this?Is it  like when a user is trying to access a page which needs authentication and after authenticating user you will redirect it to previous page which he/she trying to access?

Comment: i am not saying that use of HTTP_REFERER  is a bad idea

Comment: @Peeyush it is a bad idea, some users (like me) turn it off...

Comment: @deathApril yeah i understand that's why i am making a point about that but i just written it as a "bad idea" because i do not want to confuse him more about it

Comment: @deathApril i think he do not want to use js history method because sometime it happen tha browser loads a previously cached page and if the data is updated then to see the changes you need hit refresh again.It's not true for all website but on some website you can experience it.

Comment: @Peeyush exactly , that's why I am not using javascript .

Comment: @ShivKokroo ok but you didn't answer my first comment regarding in which case you are redirecting your user to previous page.So i can help more

Comment: My URL is somesite.com/index.php?option=com_user&view=login&return=Zm9ydW0ucGhw 
This is a joomla site . When the user logs in he is redirected to back.php , which should redirect it back to above url .

Answer (score 1):

how about ?

```
<?php
header ("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

You can use php to directly redirect the client to another page without using http's meta refresh ...

Comment: I used that code before too .
My URL is 
somesite.com/index.php?option=com_user&view=login&return=Zm9ydW0ucGhw

But when that code redirects , I am redirected to 
somesite.com/index.php?option=com_user

This is not the desired result .

Answer (score 0):

In order not to rely on the referrer, you could store the url of the page you POST the form from in a hidden input, then get it from $_POST in the script that processes the POST request and issue a redirect to that url.

A very simple example:

In the template:

```
<form action="<?= $yourDestinationUrl ?>" method="POST">
<!-- Here be your form elements -->
<input type="hidden" name="redirectTo" value="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" />
</form>
```

In the script processing the POST request:

```
[your logic goes here]

if(!empty($_POST['redirectTo']) {
    header('Location: ' . $_POST['redirectTo']);
    die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used like that:

1 - In previous page I get the complete url and add like parameter, the last parameter.

```
$e = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
href="www.nextpage.com?x=yours_parameters&e=<?php echo $e; ?>"
```

2 - In actual page, you must get e value

```
$_SESSION["url"] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$link = explode("e=",$_SESSION["url"]);
$e = $link[1];
```

3 -So, the var $e will be your back url

```
<script>location.href='$e';</script>";
```